# ontouch in surfaceview

Tags: android, touch, surfaceview

I am working on implementing SurfaceView as a customView in my xml file. and i want to add ontouch method to it. but its currently not drawing icon image. any one please help me out here and please also answer how to add ontouch method to it.

1. problem - Its not drawing bitmap.
2. question - how to add touch method in it.

My xml file.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:gif="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<rahul.surfacetest.ImageClass        
    android:id="@+id/viw"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/them"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingTop="200dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Its my main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ImageClass Is;
static float x,y=0;
Bitmap bmp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Is=(ImageClass)findViewById(R.id.viw);
    bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);       
}
}
```

Its my surface class

```
public class ImageClass extends SurfaceView implements OnTouchListener,Runnable { 

float x,y;
SurfaceHolder holder;
boolean isItOk = true;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Paint p = new Paint();

public ImageClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    y=x=10;
    holder = getHolder();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x=event.getX();
        y=event.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        x=event.getX();
        y=event.getY();         
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x=event.getX();
        y=event.getY();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;        
}


@Override
public void run() {

    Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, x,y, null);
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

}
}
```

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how Runnable and SurfaceView work. Try following this tutorial: http://blog.wisecells.com/2012/06/04/surface-view-android/ Notice the use of Threads to achieve drawing.

Comment: Wonderful! - I will provide it as an answer, if you wouldn't mind marking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding how Runnable and SurfaceView work. Try following [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/03/create-animation-on-surfaceview-in.html). Notice the use of Threads to achieve drawing.

Comment: The link should be fixed now.

Comment: Yeah link is fixed but very less understandable and google couldn't translate it. (tried more than 10 times translating it. It didn't work out).

Comment: Hmm.. it was working when I first tried it, but it may have been cached. I've linked a different, simpler tutorial, though honestly just googling "android surface view thread" should be sufficient.

Comment: I got an understanding over SurfaceView 3 days ago but when I visited this question, there was one and only answer that was yours and the link in it was not working???. If there were other answers I wouldn't have bothered in the first place.